# Convert S3 files to .csv using airflow task

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, airflow

I have an airflow task which fetches data from Redshift, creates a file out of it and loads in an s3 bucket. I want the files to be ending with .csv, but the unload command doesn't allow that. How can add a new task in the same dag to convert the files to .csv files?

The flow has to be:

task: unload the output of query to s3 bucket >> task2:convert those files into .csv

Answer (score 0):

Just add another rename task after the file is downloaded in the airflow dag.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit late but Redshift recently added EXTENSION parameter that solves this problem:

1.0.45698 – Released on January 20, 2023
Release notes for this version:

- Adds a file extension parameter to the UNLOAD command, so file extensions are automatically added to filenames.